# How to match array values from one array block with another and show result in table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to display report in table related to car rates. Specific employees are in charge to rate some cars and add a comment. I got confused as I am not sure how to do it, this is how I started and got stuck:

Table employees

```
ID | Name
1    John
2    Mark
3    Mario
4    Markus
```

Table cars

```
ID | Name
1    Audi
2    Audi S6
3    Audi Q5
4    Audi M5
```

Table  employee_can_rate

```
ID  | carID   | employeeID
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       1           4
```

Table car_rates

```
ID   |   carID   |    employeeID   | rate  | month  | year  |   comment 
1         1                3           10      11      2022     All good
2         1                2           8       11      2022     Nothing specific
3         1                4           6       11      2022     Bad engine
```

Now my goal is to create a table that will look like this
[image: desired table look]

Code..

```
<?php
$month = $_POST['month']; //lets assume it is 11
$year = $_POST['year'];

$stmt = "SELECT * FROM cars"
$q = $conn->query($stmt);

$cars = array();
while($r = $q ->fetch()){
  $cars[] = $r;
}

foreach($cars as $car){
  $stmt = "SELECT a.ID, b.Name FROM employee_can_rate a 
           LEFT JOIN employees b ON a.employeeID = b.ID";
  $q = $conn->query($stmt);
  
  while($r = $q ->fetch()){
     $employees[] = $r;
  }
}
?>
<?php 
foreach($cars as $car){ ?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th colspan="2">Car <?= $car['Name']?></th>  
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $countOcjenjuje ?>" style="text-align:center;"> Employees can rate </th> 
            <th rowspan="2">Average rate </th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php 
            foreach($employees as $employee){ 
            ?>
            <th colspan=""><?php echo $employee["Name"]?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><?= $month .' / '.$year?></td>
            <?php 
             
                // Here I need to match rates with employees and add a comment below
                    
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $rr["ocjena"]; ?></td>
            <?php } else{ ?>
            <td>No rate</td><?php }  
            } } ?>
            <td rowspan="2">Average rate result</td>                                                
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: You should join all 4 tables in a single query, not use additional queries in the loop. You're also not querying `car_rates`.

Comment: You're not using `$car` anywhere in the first `foreach` loop. You're just doing the same query over and over.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `employee_can_rate` table? Are you supposed to ignore any ratings in `car_rates` that aren't in that table?

Comment: @Barmar yes, I used that table to show only rates from employees that can rate that car. There are many employees but only few can rate car model. And I want to show only those employees and their rates. If the rate is not provided by employee I wanted to add no rate so we know he didnt provide rate

Comment: Calculating the `colspan` of the `Employees can rate` column of the table will be complicated, because you have to get the maximum number of employees who rated in any month.

Comment: Oh, that makes it easier if you want to leave a blank for no rate that month, since you only need the max that can rate, which is the same over time, not how many did rate.

Comment: Yes it is important to show all employees that are responsible for rating but some of them may not rate it,  that is why I cannot make joins in one query I guess